# Реализация урона по врагам

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код отнимание ХП у врагов, но он не работает.

```
﻿void OnTriggerStay (Collider other) {  
    if (other.CompareTag ("Enemy")) {  
        enemy = other.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.E)){ 
            enemy.HP -= Damage;
        } 
    }  
}
```

Как правильно реализовать отнимание ХП у врагов?

Comment: То есть он должен просто отнять, без каких либо действий, вида: дистанция, сила атаки и т.д., где хоть одна формула и расчет?

Comment: Сначало ловит Trigger, потом сравнение по тегу, потом проверка что клавиша отпускается... Ты уверен, что все эти 3 события произойдут в одно мгновение?) Особенно проверка на то, что клавиша отпускается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласен с @Xumera_hZ, ошибка в `Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.E)`. Вероятно вы неправильно понимаете как работает ввод и проверяете что клавиша не нажата. Есть три метода на проверку клавиш:

1. `GetKeyDown` - клавиша только что была нажата,
2. `GetKey` - клавиша в нажатом состоянии,
3. `GetKeyUp` - клавишу только что отпустили.

Поэтому в вашем случае угадать чтобы столкновение совпало с мигом когда вы отпускаете клавишу `E` практически нереально.

То есть если вы хотите проверить что клавиша отжата, то проверяйте

```
if (!Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E)){ 
        enemy.HP -= Damage;
    }
```